# Парсить div с изображениями

Tags: php, парсер, изображения

Подскажите, нужно спарить div в котором находятся изображения. (т.е. весь блок) Но на данный момент получается парсить только текст, а при попытке парсинга div с изображениями - null. Подскажите, что не так?

```
    function Parse($p1, $p2, $p3) {
    $num1 = strpos($p1, $p2);
    if ($num1 === false) return 0;
    $num2 = substr($p1, $num1);
    return strip_tags(substr($num2, 0, strpos($num2, $p3)));
}

$String = file_get_contents('http://сайт.ru');
echo Parse($String, '<div class="unique item">', '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать simple_html_dom.php.

`$html = str_get_html(file_get_contents('http://сайт.ru'));
$photosrc = "http:" . $html->find('div', $div)->find('img', 0)->src;`

Comment: <?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html(file_get_contents('http://сайт.ru'));
$photosrc = "http:" . $html->find('b-mini-gallery__box', $div)->find('img', 0)->src;
?> Старица даже не загружается

Comment: $div = порядковому номеру блока div из которого нужно достать картинку

Comment: А другие способы имеются?

Comment: должны быть. Мне как-то подошел именно этот